# Sharepoint 2013: My sharepoint solution doesn't contain default.aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I created a sharepoint application in which I added a web app item , but the problem i didn't find the default.aspx page

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the web application, you need at least a site collection to be able to navigate to. Once you [create a site collection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263094(v=office.15).aspx), every site in it (including the root site) will have a page called `Home.aspx` - that's the default one for SharePoint, not `default.aspx` - which you can browse. Also by default, navigating to a site's URL without a page name in the URL will lead you to `Home.aspx.`

**Edit, to answer OP's comment:**

> i created a new web part in visual studio in order to deploy it in my Sharepoint site. In visual studio , i created an empty sharepoint project in which i added a web part to it , the problem i didn't find the default.aspx page in the project that i created

Web part and visual web part projects don't include pages. You may include a page in a `module` if you wish, but you will have to create it yourself.

Also, visual web parts are more like user controls than ASP.NET pages. You create these to add to web part zones pages. If you want to deploy pages, you might want to choose another project type.

Comment: in fact , i created a new web part in visual studio in order to deploy it in my Sharepoint site.
In visual studio , i created an empty sharepoint project in which i added a web part to it , 
the problem i didn't find the default.aspx page in the project that i created

Comment: I'd also add that if you want to have source control, you should be creating these projects as Features and deploying them as Solutions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231517.aspx